# Initial value of the error variance to generate random variable

Tags: r, optimization, likelihood, algorithms, random-generation

We have, $y_{ij}=x_i(t_{ij})+e_{ij}$ where $y_i|u_i \sim N(x_i(t_i),\sigma_e^2I_{m_i})$ and $f(y_i)=\int_u f(y_i|u)f(u)du$ and $u_i\sim N(0,1)$. and $e_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma_e^2)$.

I am gonna use an algorithm to estimate the variance $\sigma_e^2$ that maximize the likelihood $l=\sum_{i=1}^n log f(y_i)$. For the algorithm we need to assume an initial value for $\sigma_e^2$.

FYI, $x_i(t)$ is a non-linear function that involves parameter $c$ and $A$ that we also need to estimate. So basically we are estimating three parameters in the algorithm and I know how to initialize the value of $c$ and $A$, but not $\sigma_e^2$.

My first question, is there any strategy  to initialize the value of the variance in this kind of situation since we can't get the sample variance(we need to generate the random variable $y_i$).

I tried to use standard normal variance for $e_i$, but if I do that we get some negative $y_i$ and so some $logf(y_i)$ give NAN and so can't get the likelihood value.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear:

1. if you want to maximise the log-likelihood function $\ell(c,A,\sigma_e|\mathbf y)$, it depends on observations, not on simulations : if one simulates the $y_{ij}$'s, the value of $\sigma_e$ is required
2. if $y_{ij}=x_i(t_{ij})+e_{ij}$ with $e_{ij}\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma_e^2)$, where are the $u_i$'s involved? It should be written as $y_{ij}=x_i(t_{ij},u_i)+e_{ij}$
3. nothing in the model seems to prohibit negative values for the $y_{ij}$'s as the likelihood involves
   $$\int \frac{1}{\sigma_e^{\sum_i m_i}}\exp\left\{-\sum_{ij}(y_{ij}-x_i(t_{ij},\mathbf u))^2/2\sigma_e^2\right\} f(u)\,\text d\mathbf u$$or a Monte Carlo version
   $$\frac{1}{\sigma_e^{\sum_i m_i}}\sum_v \exp\left\{-\sum_{ij}(y_{ij}-x_i(t_{ij},\mathbf u^v))^2/2\sigma_e^2\right\}$$
4. "the algorithm" [for maximising the likelihood] is not described, hence it is unclear why an arbitrary positive value of $\sigma_e$ cannot not operate as its starting value.

Comment: @ 1. I think we are maximizing $l(y,A,\sigma_e)$ not  $l(x,A,\sigma_e)$. 2. $x_i$ is a function of $u$, $c$ and $A$. 3. I feel that too, but if it's negative how can we calculate likelihood? Theoretically $x_i$'s  is non-negative, but in practice it is gonna be large enough that $y$ should be positive too. 4. I haven't wrote down the algorithm yet(this question arise at the very beginning while trying to create).

Comment: The very basic summary algorithm of generating $y_i$ is:   ◮ To generate a random variable y using such a representation,
⊲ we can first generate a variable u from the distribution
⊲ Then generate y from the selected conditional distribution

Comment: You still do not indicate why the $y_{ij}$'s need being simulated